# Console GUI Haskell on Windows

Tags: haskell

I'm parsing some RSS feed and I want to present to the user in a nicely formatted way(with features such as using the arrow key to scroll and select the feed items) and I can use the brick library on Linux but I can't install this library on Windows.
Any alternatives on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ansi-terminal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal) could do it for you. It works on both.